# I have a problem using varaiable range in combo box

Tags: vba, variables, combobox, range

This is my code:-

```
Public CBR As Range
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim cbvalue As String
Set CBR = Range("b1")
Call Copy_header
 End Sub
Sub Copy_header()
Workbooks("Book2").Worksheets("DropDown").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range.CBR.Select  
End Sub
```

1. CBR is come as "DOS" or "NDC
2. I tried to put CBR as range in module also but not working

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I don't know what you are doing, but this may help:
(Indented and spaced)

```
Option Explicit

Public CBR As String

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  Dim cbvalue As String
  CBR = "b1"
  Call Copy_header
End Sub

Sub Copy_header()
  Workbooks("Book2").Worksheets("DropDown").Activate
  ActiveSheet.Range(CBR).Select
End Sub
```

EDIT: This is closer to what you have:

```
Public CBR As Range

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  Dim cbvalue As String
  Set CBR = Workbooks("Book2").Worksheets("DropDown").Range("b1")
  Call Copy_header
End Sub

Sub Copy_header()
' Workbooks("Book2").Worksheets("DropDown").Activate
' ActiveSheet.Range.CBR.Select
  CBR.Worksheet.Activate
  CBR.Select
End Sub
```

EDIT 2: A lot of people don't know this: (Meaning I didn't know this)
That the range includes the workbook and the worksheet!

```
Option Explicit

Sub sub1()
  Dim range1 As Range, range2 As Range
  ThisWorkbook.Activate
  Sheets("sheet1").Activate
  Set range1 = Range("a1")
  Set range2 = Workbooks("book2").Sheets("sheet2").Range("b2")
  Debug.Print "Range1: ", range1.Worksheet.Parent.Name, range1.Worksheet.Name, range1.Address
  Debug.Print "Range2: ", range2.Worksheet.Parent.Name, range2.Worksheet.Name, range2.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: Tahnks it worked